# compute columns means after assigning one dataframe to a field of another data frame R

Tags: r

I have one data frame for example:

```
    > df=data.frame(a=1:4,b=2:5)
    > df
    a b
    1 1 2
    2 2 3
    3 3 4
    4 4 5
```

Then I create another data frame and assign the data frame above to a field of the other one:

```
    > df2=data.frame(c=3:6)
    > df2$df1=df
    > df2
      c df1.a df1.b
    1 3     1     2
    2 4     2     3
    3 5     3     4
    4 6     4     5
```

When I compute the column means of the data frame, I got the error:

```
> colMeans(df2)
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Could anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Also see `str(df2)`. You have a nested list (ie, a data.frame within a data.frame).

Answer (score 1):

Check `ncol(df2)` to see that there are only 2 "columns". The `colMeans` function cannot take the mean of the second element of the `df2` list because it isn't a single column but two. Instead of `df2$df1 = df`, you can do `df2 <- cbind(df2, df)`. If you want the column names to be the same as in your example you can do

```
sapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) df2[,paste0('df1','.',names(df)[i])] <<- df[,i])
```